# AngularJS, UI Bootstrap Carousel link to a specific slide from a different view

Tags: angularjs, carousel, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to click through to a different view, with a specific slide in a Bootstrap UI Carousel open.

I've been able to create a button that goes to a specific slide by using the active property:

```
$scope.setActive = function(idx) {
   $scope.slides[idx].active=true;
```

but I can't seem to figure out how to link to another view and also open a specific slide.

Here's a plunker that show's my attempt so far. In this example I'm trying to link to the home.html with slide two open from page.html.

http://plnkr.co/edit/MXK8Auhc89AKMcoyy0Jn?p=preview

I'm new to AngularJS so there might be a very simple answer to this that I'm over looking.

I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [$routeParams](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams) for this. Here is working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/Ky2HEpOYuqtgqsTSUr1x?p=preview

```
 //in app.config
 .when('/home/:slide', {
    //introducing slide as parameter here
    templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
    controller: 'SlideController'
  })


//in Ctrl controller
$scope.setActive($route.current.params.slide || 0);


<!--resulting link for page.html-->
    <a href="#home/1">View Second Slide</a>
```

**second** item of the array is `array_name[1]`.